# Bash script for LDAP website API requests

Tags: bash, api, curl

I want to automate and create a bash script where I have this call:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer <PANDA TOKEN HERE>" https://www.websitehere.com/api/v2/groups/GROUP NAME/details
```

My goal is for the bash script to iterate over a list of group names (GROUP NAME).I have my panda token working. Unfortunately I have no previous experience with bash. I have installed WSL and curl.

I tried this bash script, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

group_details=("acton_team_coordinators" "acs-peripherals" "admingrocery" "ae-central-leads")

for group in "${group_details[@]}"
do
    curl -v GET " https://www.websitehere.com/api/v2/groups/acton_team_coordinators/details" -H "<PANDA TOKEN HERE>”
done
```

I got error in CMD like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bg4H.png)

Comment: You've got a good start for a script here. I don't see where you are using the `$group` variable that you create at the top of your `for` loop. I'm assuming you need to embed it in the URL you are submitting with `curl`. Look more closely at a URL that has returned data from `www.websitehere.com` and see if you can spot where the `group` value is. Oftentimes it will be something like `https://www......&group=MyGroup`. Good luck.

Comment: But, please don't expect readers to goto external sites to look at something that can be included in the body of your question. Just copy/paste the `CMD` error in to replace that link AND while the text is still highlighted, click the `{}` tool in the Edit menu that is at the top of the Edit "window" you are using. This will format your text in the more readable `code/data/output/errMsg` plain text format. Good luck.

Comment: One more trick for your code, you'll probably want to save that data once you get your query working, so `curl ..... > /path/to/data/${group}.$(date +'%Y-%m-%d').dat` might help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to code the "**group**" variable as a variable, by prefixing it with the "**$**".

It is good practice to surround variable strings with a pair of braces ("**{}**"), because there are cases where confusion can occur in determining what is the actual variable name.

You also had **space inside the double-quotes**, before the "http ...".  I am not sure if that could create issues, but best to remove that space and avoid them.

**The modified script** would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

out_capture="somewhere"

group_details=("acton_team_coordinators" "acs-peripherals" "admingrocery" "ae-central-leads")

for group in "${group_details[@]}"
do
    curl -v GET "https://www.websitehere.com/api/v2/groups/${group}/details" -H "<PANDA TOKEN HERE>" >${out_capture}/${group}.out
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this scripts should I run from the CMD or from the WSL app?

Comment: By referencing WSL, you indicate you are doing this from Windows.  You **will** need to run from the WSL app for correct interpretation of the bash script.  But you should already know this, yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the script working, and used gitbash to run it. DO you have any idea how to amend the script so I can download the responses in csv or json locally?
Here is the working script:
"
group=("acton_team_coordinators" "acs-peripherals" "admingrocery" "ae-central-leads" "600s-data-access-group" "Abacus Enterprise")
for group in "${group[@]}"
do
    curl -v GET https://www.websitehere.com/api/v2/groups/${group}/details -H "Authorization: Bearer PANDA TOKEN HERE"
done
"

Comment: Generating the response in CSV or json format is entirely controlled by the command run on the remote server.  You need to formulate that correctly.  I have no experience with getting those formats.  The next question is ... do you want to save for each group separately, or as a single comprehensive output?  Lastly, you use "group" as both the variable in "for" and the name of the "array".  That is a logic conflict, so you WILL NOT get what you want.  Those need to be different.

Comment: Updated script in answer for separately stored output.